# fastest way to compare data between 2 csv files before inserting it to database

Tags: laravel

so I have 2 CSV files (user and bank_account) that I want to insert into my database, these 2 files have the **user_number** field that connected these two files, some user data doesn't have **bank_account** data. I want to insert to the database only user that has bank_account.
I've tried to compare a user with a bank account for each loop, so if there are 1000 **bank_accounts** one user will loop 1000 times if the bank account not exists and it takes really long time. I want to know if there's a way to do it faster thanks. I'm using Laravel

Comment: I hope below will helps you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37719160/compare-the-data-of-two-csv-file-php
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50107166/faster-way-to-compute-difference-between-two-csv-files